# Does Oracle Spatial have equivalents of ST_IsClosed ST_IsRing ST_IsSimple

Tags: oracle-spatial, ogc

I'm trying to find the equivalent in Oracle Spatial of the above OGC functions. I know there's not a direct function I can call, does anyone know of a workaround to get these functions by combining other functions? For closed I could get the first and last points and check they are equal, but that might be either A) Missing something or B) very inefficient.

Comment: does Oracle implement either OGC simple features for SQL or [SQL/MM](http://doesen0.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/proceedings/paper/68.pdf)

Comment: Been a while, but I think you can  determine these properties from the [SDO_GTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/spatial-datatypes-metadata.html#GUID-4D84CE67-67E4-4A84-8255-C586E765A94B) of the SDO_GEOMETRY.

Comment: Not that I can see, it returns identical values for closed and non closed linestrings for example.

Comment: And if you first call [SDO_MIGRATE.TO_CURRENT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_MIGRATE-reference.html#GUID-60525DFE-EE7A-4302-BFC9-5F9CDBF9728E) on the SDO_GEOMETRY?

Comment: Not sure how that would help. The column is already at the most current version of Oracle Spatial?

Comment: Depending on your data, the validation function could be useful  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-validate_geometry_with_context.htm#SPATL1130

Comment: This will return true for valid geometries but doesn't help with Closed, Ring or Simple.

Comment: If a polygon is valid it is simple, it has rings, and all the rings are closed. But I believe that your aim is not to check the validity of polygons but something else.

Comment: My aim is to be able to call functionally identical functions to the ST_ functions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was a struggle, but I managed to get all the functions implemented. If anyone finds this in future here's where I landed:

**ST_IsSimple**

```
ST_GEOMETRY(GEO_COLUMN).ST_ISSIMPLE()
```

**ST_IsClosed**

```
(CASE WHEN SDO_RELATE(SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT(GEO_COLUMN), SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_END_PT(GEO_COLUMN), 'mask=EQUAL') = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

**ST_IsRing**

```
(CASE WHEN (SDO_RELATE(SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT(GEO_COLUMN), SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_END_PT(GEO_COLUMN), 'mask=EQUAL') = 'TRUE') AND (ST_GEOMETRY(GEO_COLUMN).ST_ISSIMPLE() = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

A lot more long winded than I expected, but then, it is Oracle, and doing anything is usually a long slog.